# Conditional intent with reasonable belief that the condition cannot be met

Tags: england-and-wales, intent

> D1 and D2 carry out a burglary (offence A). D1 acts as principal,
> entering the premises and stealing. D2 assists or encourages D1 by
> acting as a lookout. However, In the course of the burglary, D1 kills
> householder V, with intent to kill or do really serious harm. D1 is
> liable for murder of V as a principal. D2 may also be liable for
> murder, as a secondary party, if D2 intended or conditionally intended
> that crime B should be committed, if the occasion arose.

https://www.cps.gov.uk/legal-guidance/secondary-liability-charging-decisions-principals-and-accessories

Suppose D2 reasonably believes the occasion won't arise that D1 commit murder. Suppose the burglary is of an abandoned property that no-one has visited for a long time and they don't think D2 is armed. Can they nevertheless conditionally intend the murder as a secondary party?

Must conditional intent include some specific form of belief that the condition can be met? Or is any act which brings about a result intentional whenever the result is conditionally desired?